# Copy values from one column to another column of a data frame based on a criteria in R

Tags: r, replace, copy

I think similar questions have been asked before but I am still a bit confused.

[image]

The image attached shows how my data looks like. However, I would like to replace whenever "N/A" appears in Sample_Location with the corresponding value in Sample_Address. the expected result is attached below

[image]

Appreciate if someone could help out please.

thanks

Comment: Hi Arun. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not post images of code or data here. Read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for this info. Apologies I did not look into this in more detail. Will take note henceforth to make my qs better.